# Getting Looped Output into an Appended Object

Tags: r, for-loop, output, rbind

So I am trying to make a basic sensitivity analysis script. The outputs come out as I want via the print I added to the end of the script. Issue is that I would like a tibble or object that has all the outputs appended together that I can export as a csv or xlsx.

I created two functions, sens_analysis which runs all the code, and multiply_across which multiplies across each possible percentage across each possible column of your table. You need multiply_across to run the sens_analysis.

I would normally like a title but instead I just added an indicator column instead that I can sort by.

I made everything with mtcars so it should be easy to replicate, the issue is that I just have a huge print at the end; not an object that I can manipulate or pull from for other analysis.

I have been trying the rbind, bind_row, appending rows in a variety of ways. 
Or building a new object. As you can see in the code at line (18) I make something called output that I have tried to populate, which hasn't gone well.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
library(xtable)

data<-mtcars
percent<-c(.05,.1,.15)
goods<-c("hp","gear","wt")
weight<-c(6,7,8)
disagg<-"cyl"
func<-median

sens_analysis<-function(data=data, goods=goods, weight=weight, disagg=disagg, precent=percent, func=func){
  output<-NULL%>%
    as.tibble()
  basket<-(rbind(goods,weight))
  percent<-c(0,percent,(percent*-1))
  percent_to_1<-percent+1


  data_select<-data%>%
    dplyr::select(c(goods,disagg))%>%
    group_by_at(disagg)%>%
    summarise_at(.vars = goods ,.funs = func)%>%
    as_tibble()

  data_select_weight<-purrr::map2(data_select[,-1], as.numeric(basket[2,]),function(var, weight){
    var*weight
  })%>% as_tibble %>%
    add_column(data_select[,1], .before = 1)
  colnames(data_select_weight)[1]<-disagg


  multiply_across(data_select_weight,percent_to_1)
  return(output) 
  #output2<-rbind(output2,output)                        
}

############################
multiply_across<-function(data=data_select_weight,list=percent_to_1){
  varlist<-names(data[,-1]) 
  for(i in varlist){
    df1 = data[,i]
    for(j in list){
      df<-data
      df[,i]<-round(df1*j,2)
      df<-mutate(df, total = round(rowSums(df[,-1]),2))%>%
        mutate(type=paste0(i," BY ",(as.numeric(j)-1)*100,"% OVER ",disagg))%>%
       print(df) 

      #output<-bind_rows(output,df)
      #output<-bind_rows(output,df)
      #output[[j]]<-df[[j]]
    }  

  }

}

##############################################################################################
sens_analysis(data,goods,weight,disagg,percent,func)
```

The expected result if you just run the code straight-up should just be a bunch of printed tibbles, that arent in an object.  But ideally, for future analysis on the data or easy of use, a table of the outputs appended together would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and will add my answer here in case someone else hits this issues.

I created a list within loops and then binded those lists together.

Just focus on the binding rows outside the right for-loop.

```
multiply_across<-function(data=data_select_weight,
  list=percent_to_1){
  varlist <- colnames(data[, -1])
  output_list <- list()
  for (i in varlist) {
    df1 <- data[,i]
    for (j in list) {
      name <- paste0(i, " BY ", (as.numeric(j)-1)*100, "% OVER ", disagg)

      df <- as_tibble(data)
      df[,i] <- round(df1*j, 2)
      df <- mutate(df, total = round(rowSums(df[,-1]),2))%>%
            mutate(type = paste0(i, " BY ", (as.numeric(j)-1)*100, "% OVER ", disagg))
      df<-df[,c(6,1,2,3,4,5)]


      output_list[[paste0(i," BY ",(as.numeric(j)-1)*100)]] <- (assign(paste0(i," BY ",(as.numeric(j)-1)*100,"% OVER ",disagg),df))

    }

  }

  bind_rows(lapply(output_list,
    as.data.frame.list,
    stringsAsFactors=F))

}
```